# How to avoid that a WIDE item push all the other columns?

Tags: pstricks, workflow, psmatrix

I´m trying to finish my flowchart (with the inestimable help of Herbert and Bernard)

How to avoid that a WIDE item (with no elements on its sides) push all the other columns??
I want the othe columns be in the same place as WIDE ITEM were a normal item (or it donesn´t exists.)

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}

\usepackage{pstricks}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{18cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize



\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2cm}
\def\pscolhookiii{\psset[pst-node]{mcol = l}}


\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2,colsep=0.1]% defines the distance between two frames
%
 & [name = SA]
  \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.15){Solución Actual}&
    \\[1.2cm]
%
    & [name=GV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)%
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.55,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.15){Generar Vecindad}
    \\[1.2cm]
    %~\\
   & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=0.1,name = Vvacia]
    \begin{tabular}{c}¿Vecindad=$\emptyset$? \end{tabular}
   & [mnode = oval, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.22,name = LTfin]
    \begin{tabular}{c}$\bullet$Finalizar\\$\bullet$Eligir Mejor\\Solución Visitada\end{tabular}
    \\[0.75cm]
%
  [name=Wr]
   \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=0.09,opacity=0.3}
    \psline(0.40,0.40)(0.90,-0.10)
    \psline(0.40,-0.10)(0.90,0.40)
    \rput[t](0,-1.15){Eliminar Vecino Elegido}


     & [name=EMV]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodeblue(0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    \cnodepink(-0.75,-0.55){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(-0.05,-0.5){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.65,-0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnodepink(0.35,-0.40){0.15}{Current}
    \rput[t](0,-1.15){Elegir Mejor Vecino}&
    \\[1cm]
%
    [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = CA]
    \begin{tabular}{c}¿Verifica\\Criterio de\\Aspiración?\end{tabular}
    & [mnode = dia, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.2,name = LT]
    \begin{tabular}{c}¿Está en\\Lista Tabú? \end{tabular}
    \\[0.32cm]
%
    & [name=Ace, mnode = r]
    \psframegray(-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnodegreen(0.65,0.15){0.15}{Boa}
    \psline[linewidth=0.1]{->}(1.5,-0.2)(0.84,0.16)
    %\rput[t](0,-1.15){\tabular{c}$\bullet$ Actualizar Lista Tabú\\$\bullet$ Aceptar Vecino Elegido como nueva solución\\$\bullet$ Repetir proceso hasta alcanzar el máximmo de iteraciones.\\$\bullet$ Si se han agotado la iteraciones,\\ tomar como Solución, la mejor de todas las visitadas\endtabular}
    &\\[1cm]
    & 
    [mnode = oval, shadow=true, linearc = 0.05,framesep=-0.22,name = Repetir]
    \begin{tabular}{c}$\bullet$ Actualizar Lista Tabú\\$\bullet$ Aceptar Vecino Elegido como nueva solución\\$\bullet$ Repetir proceso hasta alcanzar el máximmo de iteraciones.\\$\bullet$ Si se han agotado la iteraciones,\\ tomar como Solución, la mejor de todas las visitadas \end{tabular} & 


\end{psmatrix}
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab}
\ncline{LT}{CA}_{Si}
{\psset{nodesepB = 1.15}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.52cm]{SA}{GV}%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.52cm,nodesepB=0.32]{GV}{Vvacia}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.40cm]{Vvacia}{EMV}^{No}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 0.1cm]{Vvacia}{Vfin}
 %\ncline[nodesepA = 1.52cm]{GV}{EMV}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 9pt]{LT}{Ace}^{No}
 \ncline[nodesepB = 1.52cm]{CA}{Wr}^{No}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 7pt, angleA = -90]{CA}{Ace}^{Si} }%
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.67cm]{EMV}{LT}%%
 \midAB(GV)(EMV){I}
 \ncangle[nodesepA = 1.15, angleA = 90]{Wr}{Vvacia}
 \ncline[nodesepA = 1.45cm]{Ace}{Repetir}
}


\end{document}
```

---

This issue solved could help me to do flowcharts similar to this one, where you can see in row 3 that a part of 2 item are under one column )
[image]

Comment: Use `\psspan` like documented in `texdoc psmatrix`.

Comment: @christoph , Yes I think that´s the solution but I was tryiing and the result is no good becausse: 1.- gives a strange result, and with other the bottom oval is not aligned with the 2nd col, and the ncline doesn´t go stright.

Comment: I also didn't get it to align with the second column. Thats why I didn't post an answer, yet :) I'll have a look

Comment: BTW, for your Figure 2 the package [`pst-tree`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-tree/pst-tree) might be better than `psmatrix`.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to rescale to 18cm!

```
[...]
\begin{document}
\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%     if you want to resize
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}

[...]

    &\\[1cm]
 & [name=Repetir] \makebox[0pt]{\psovalbox[shadow,framesep=-0.22]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}$\bullet$ Actualizar Lista Tabú\\$\bullet$ Aceptar Vecino Elegido como nueva solución\\$\bullet$ 

[...]
```

[image]